# What's the difference between @State and @StateObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a model like this

```
import Foundation

class Play:ObservableObject{
    @Published var name:String="Tayle"
    @Published var age:Int=12
}
```

It will be used in two views

For example:

```
struct Demo: View {
    //1
    @State private var play:Play = Play()
    //2
    //@StateObject private var play:Play = Play()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: PlayNameView(play: play)){
                Text("go to platnbame")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlayNameView:View{
    @ObservedObject var play:Play
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Text("Hello,\(play.name)")
            Button(action:{
                play.name="iop"
            }){
                Text("change the name to:iop")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the project,they have the same behavior. If @StateObject can do it,why choose @State

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@State` is a variable that is meant to hold value types such as Bools, Integers, Strings, structs  and so on. Apple simply doesn't intend for `@State` to be used on reference types such as `ObservableObjects`, because once again, State is meant to store value types such as Int, not instances of classes. Apple says in the documentation,

> Don’t use state properties for persistent storage because the life cycle of state variables mirrors the view life cycle. Instead, use them to manage transient state that only affects the user interface, like the highlight state of a button, filter settings, or the currently selected list item.

In short, you could use `@State` variables to store, say, the number of times a user has clicked a button (since the app started), but not to store another `ObservableObject`. Also, if you look at [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-vs-stateobject-vs-observedobject-vs-environmentobject-in-swiftui-81e2913d63f9#:%7E:text=Use%20%40%20State%20for%20very%20simple,than%20what%20%40State%20can%20handle.), the article shows that using an Object with State will not cause the view's actual variable to update. This is because, again to quote the article,

> Because we’re using a complex, reference type, the value of state itself never changes. While a property of state , num has changed, the @State property wrapper has no idea because it is only watching the variable state, not any of its properties. To SwiftUI, because it is only watching state, it has no idea that num has changed, and so never re-renders the view.

An `@StateObject`, on the other hand, can store things such as `ObservableObjects`. When the value of the Object changes, it will cause a view update, because all of it is observed by `SwiftUI`. This will only happen with `@Published` properties, though, and any change of those properties will, once again, cause the view to re-render. An important note, too: `@StateObject` will create a new instance every time the view appears. If you need to persist the values, you would need to pass in the object from a more root view. Also, an `@StateObject` can be changed from outside the view, whereas `@State` variables are only intended to be private and local. For more information on why this is, refer to the Apple `State` documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Resources:

1. https://story.tomasen.org/swiftui-difference-of-state-binding-environment-and-environmentobject-and-when-to-use-them-ff80699f45b7
2. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-stateobject-property-wrapper
3. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject
4. [https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-vs-stateobject-vs-observedobject-vs-environmentobject-in-swiftui-81e2913d63f9#:~:text=Use%20%40%20State%20for%20very%20simple,than%20what%20%40State%20can%20handle](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/state-vs-stateobject-vs-observedobject-vs-environmentobject-in-swiftui-81e2913d63f9#:%7E:text=Use%20%40%20State%20for%20very%20simple,than%20what%20%40State%20can%20handle).

Comment: wait a second now, how can I use a struct with @StateObject? StateObject needs the variable to conform to ObservableObject which struct cannot do!

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter You're correct - I removed that error.

Comment: i mean you can still use a @State with and class object, as the reassignment of the property causes an update, what might be just what you want

Answer (score 6):

For Objects use the `@StateObject` property wrapper. For String, Int, etc use `@State` property wrapper.

`@State`: We use this property wrapper when we observe a property that is exists inside our ContentView.

`@StateObject`: We use this property wrapper when we are observing properties that exists outside of our ContentView like in our Object, we can observe that property changes by firstly conforming that class to `ObservableObject` Protocol and marking that property as `@Published` inside our Object.

Comment: nah wait, thats not right @ StateObject should be used when the View owns the object... the situation you describe should be handled by @ ObservedObject

Answer (score 0):

One more consideration for `@State` vs `@StateObject` **before iOS 17**'s `@Observable` Macro:

> Even if the variable is a `class`, sometimes it still makes sense to use `@State`.

In general, `@State` is intended for value types, while `@StateObject` is intended for reference types - classes that conform to `ObservableObject` protocol in specific.

However, SwiftUI before iOS 17 lacked a way to express "hey, I want to instantiate a source-of-truth object in a view, but I know that no property in that class would emit changes that trigger an UI update (nothing `@Published`)".

Someone may ask, then why not just make such a `class` a `struct`? Well, when not all source code is under your control, there are a plethora of reasons for choosing `class` over `struct` by other developers. C++ interoperability is one of them.

In this situation, because the `class` doesn't need to be an `ObservableObject`, or it is an `ObservableObject` but doesn't affect UI in the view that create it, but we still want to make it the source-of-truth, `@State` can be used instead of `@StateObject`.

Using `@State` in this situation basically means: we initialized an object in the view, and please hold the address to the object unchanged for the lifespan of the view.

---

**iOS 17+**: everything is either a `@State var`, a `@Bindable var`, or simply a `var`. How nice is that!

ref: [migration doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro).